# How to add default Widgets to a custom dynamic sidebar

Tags: wordpress

I have added my custom dynamic sidebar using this code in WordPress

```
register_sidebar
(array(
'name' => __( 'My widget' ),
'id' => 'right-sidebar',
'description' => __( 'Widgets in this area will be shown on the right-hand side.' ),
'before_title' => '<h1>',
'after_title' => '</h1>'
));
```

Now I can see this dynamic sidebar in the WordPress admin, via Dashboard -> Appearance -> Widgets.

When I activate the Theme, by default this dynamic sidebar displays no content; to display Widgets (e.g. Recent Posts, Pages, Category) I have to drag them into the My Widget dynamic sidebar.

But I want the My Widget dynamic sidebar to display three Widgets (Recent Posts, Pages, Category) by default, similar to the dynamic sidebars in Twenty Ten or Twenty Eleven.

Comment: **Note to mods**: this question would be a better fit for WPSE.

Answer (score 3):

This is fairly easy to do, using [`dynamic_sidebar()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar) and [`the_widget()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget).

This is the construct for displaying default content, if no Widgets are added to a dynamic sidebar:

```
<?php
if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'My_Widget' ) ) {
    // default content goes here
}
?>
```

So, to output specific *Widgets* as default content, simply call `the_widget($widget, $instance, $args)`. For example, to display the ["Recent Posts" Widget](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget#Recent_Posts_widget):

```
<?php
if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'My_Widget' ) ) {
    the_widget( 'WP_Widget_Recent_Posts' );
}
?>
```

(See the linked Codex references for additional usage examples, and `$instance`/`$args` values, for each Widget.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is a normal behavior, you just have to set default content for this sidebar in your theme. Take a look at twentyeleven/sidebar.php, you can do the same thing :

```
<?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'right-sidebar' ) ) : ?>
  Default content
<?php endif; ?>
```

And don't mistake, a sidebar is not a widget, it is a widget area.

Comment: it call sidebar on frontend you will see output only if in admin you have drag any thig in your right-sidebar.

Comment: I repeat : you have to set default content for your sidebar, wordpress can't automagically guess this...

Comment: yes that i am asking how to added default widget (for ex recent post ,blogroll,pages etc)  for my own sidebar (right-sidebar)

Comment: So, as I said in my answer you can easily achieve this by modifying your theme

Answer (score 0):

Its possible but not in terms of auto activate.
What you need to do in the place where you required widget (suppose sidebar) sidebar is truly widget-ready and the administrator pops a new sidebar widget into the lineup, things will automatically switch over to use the admin's specified settings.

So yes, you can do it as a default.Not as auto active...

For more information https://stackoverflow.com/a/3057665/716492